# smooth the survival curves generated with ggsurvplot?

Tags: r, plot, survival-analysis, smoothing

I'm new to stackoverflow and here is my 1st question :)
I was wondering if there was a similar function as "geom_smooth" but for plot that were generated using
 "ggsurvplot". 
Here is an example of what I want to do, using the R "ovarian" dataset:

Create a "survival object":

```
library(survival)
surv_object <- Surv(time = ovarian$futime, event = ovarian$fustat)
```

Create a "survival curve" from a previously fitted model:

```
fit1 <- survfit(surv_object ~ rx, data = ovarian)
```

plot the "survfit" object:

```
library(survminer)    
ggsurvplot(fit1, data = ovarian, pval = TRUE)
```

Thanks a lot, 
Valérian

Comment: Traditional survival curves are always step plots. It would be weird to see them as a smooth curve. Are you really sure that's what you want? If so, what technique do you want to use to "smooth" the curve? When asking for help you should always include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data that we can use to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Hi MrFlick thanks for your answer. Yes, I thought smoothing the curve would show better the (significant) treatment difference I'm trying to illustrate. Regarding the smoothing technique: I don't really know, I guess method="loess" will do. Oups, regarding the reproducile example I thought I had done enough by providing an example that uses a R dataset (i.e ovarian). I thus just produced an example to illustrate my issue and did not have any possible solutions to verify, but on which it would be possible to apply the smoothing function. Should I do it differently next time? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I didn't realize "ovarian" was a built in dataset from the survival package. Sorry, that is a good data set to use.

Comment: No prob, thanks a lot for your help

Comment: `Error in ggsurvplot(fit1, data = ovarian, pval = TRUE) : 
  could not find function "ggsurvplot"`

Comment: Hi 42, the ggsurvplot is in the package survminer. Sorry, I forgot to mention it.

Comment: @MrFlick : this is not the case for every industry. See for exemple [2018 Annual Global Corporate Default And Rating Transition Study](https://www.spratings.com/documents/20184/774196/2018AnnualGlobalCorporateDefaultAndRatingTransitionStudy.pdf) p9 cumulative default rate by rating, which is 1 - survival function.

Comment: @lcrmorin. What chart are you referring to in this document? The question still remains, exactly what smoothing technique do you want to use? How do you want to be able to interpret the resulting plot? Do you want to make a stronger modeling assumption?

Comment: The cumulative default rate by time horizon p9. I don't think it need a stronger modelling assumptions, just a simple way to plot diagonal lines between points and not a step curve with ggsurvplot.

Answer (score 2):

A "simple way to plot diagonal lines between points" can easily be extracted from the `"survfit"` object where we are interested in `time`, `surv` and the strata. Both strata have the same length, so we simply repeat a strata id `length(fit1$surv) / 2` each.

```
# survfit object
library(survival)
fit1 <- survfit(Surv(time=ovarian$futime, event=ovarian$fustat) ~ rx, data=ovarian)

# extraction
d1 <- with(fit1, data.frame(time, surv, strata=rep(1:2, each=length(surv) / 2)))
```

Then we may plot the estimates for each strata separately.

```
cols <- c("red", "blue")
plot(d1$time, d1$surv, type="n", ylim=0:1)
sapply(1:2, function(x) with(d1[d1$strata == x, ], lines(time, surv, type="l", col=cols[x])))
legend("topright", legend=c("rx1", "rx2"), lty=1, col=cols, title="Strata")
```

[image]

Or using `ggplot2`, something like this:

```
ggplot2::ggplot(d1, aes(x=time, y=surv, group=strata, col=strata)) +
  geom_line() +
  ylim(0:1) + 
  scale_colour_identity()
```

[image]

**Note** that this just scopes the programming issue, there probably need some discussions about smoothing-assumptions to be done, e.g. on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** the good answer may be [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67467087/r-smooth-survival-curve-force-start-and-end) and plotting with ggplot [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55243647/how-to-display-data-made-by-cobs-spline-package-as-ggplot2).

**Original**:
I am aware that this thread is a little old, but I just came across the same issue, as I am dealing with registry based public health data, and not allowed to publicise sensitive data. Step-wise survival plots are considered as such, so I had to figure a way to plot a smooth survival curve instead.

Below is my suggestion drawing on the excellent `ggsurvfit` package.

As the smoothing function, I am using the standard smoothing function from the `ggplot2::geom_smooth()` function for large datasets as this gives a much better look (that is also why I use the `ggsurvfit::df_colon` data set).

I would have loved to share the resulting plot, but my reputation does not allow me to share pictures. Working on it.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(survival)
library(purrr)
library(ggsurvfit)

## Data
df <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ surg, data = ggsurvfit::df_colon) |> ggsurvfit::tidy_survfit(type = "survival")

df_split <- split(df,df$strata)

df_smoothed <- purrr::reduce(lapply(c("estimate","conf.low", "conf.high"), function(j) {
  do.call(rbind,
          lapply(seq_along(df_split), function(i) {
            nms <- names(df_split)[i]
            y <-
              predict(mgcv::gam(as.formula(paste0(
                j[[1]], " ~ s(time, bs = 'cs')"
              )), data = df_split[[i]]))
            df <- data.frame(df_split[[i]]$time, y, nms)
            names(df) <- c("time", paste0(j[[1]], ".smooth"), "strata")
            df
          }))
}),dplyr::full_join) |> full_join(df)
#> Joining with `by = join_by(time, strata)`
#> Joining with `by = join_by(time, strata)`
#> Joining with `by = join_by(time, strata)`

## Plotting
ggplot(data=df_smoothed) + 
  geom_line(aes(x=time, y=estimate.smooth, color = strata))+
  geom_ribbon(aes(x=time, ymin = conf.low.smooth, ymax = conf.high.smooth, fill = strata), alpha = 0.50)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to smooth your data, but to plot curves instead of lines.

Full credit for the method goes to @Z.Lin (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54900769/9406040). Thanks also to @jay.sf for extracting the data from the survfit object.

## Data

```
library(tidyverse)
library(survival)

surv_object <- Surv(time = ovarian$futime, event = ovarian$fustat)
fit1 <- survfit(surv_object ~ rx, data = ovarian)

d1 <- with(fit1, data.frame(time, surv,
                            strata = as.factor(rep(1:2, each=length(fit1$surv) / 2))))

d2 <- d1 %>%
  group_by(strata) %>%
  summarise(x = list(spline(time, surv, n = 200, method = "natural")[["x"]]),
            y = list(spline(time, surv, n = 200, method = "natural")[["y"]])) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(cols = c("x", "y"))
```

## Plot

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data = d1,
             aes(time, surv, color = strata)) +
  geom_line(data = d2,
            aes(x, y, color = strata))
```

[image: 1]

---

## Comparison with smoothing

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data = d1,
             aes(time, surv, color = strata)) +
  geom_smooth(data = d1,
              aes(time, surv, color = strata),
              se = FALSE)
```

[image: 2]

Comment: The lines show slopes > 0 which probably doesn't make much sense in survival analysis.