# R smooth survival curve force start and end

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis, smoothing

I would like to smooth a survival curve so it has no 'steps'.
With the following data I am trying this:

```
library(ggplot2)
df1<-data.frame(y=c(1,0.99,0.97,0.95,0.94,0.94,0.82,0.72,0.58,0.34,0.20,0.12,0.11,0), 
time=c(3,4,7,8,10,11,13,14,15,17,20,22,23,24))
ggplot(df1, aes(time,y)) + geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "gam", formula = y ~ poly(x, 2),se=F)
```

[image]

But the smoothed line has start point higher than one as well as end point lower than 0 ( Which for a survival plot is impossible).
How could fit a line that:

1. Line start at y,x values= 1,0
2. ends at y,x values=0,24
3. always monotonic decreasing function

Comment: You could break down the steps. First estimate the `gam`. Then take the predicted values using something like `predict(model, newData = data.frame(time=0:25))`. Then truncate them to within `[0, 1]`. Then plot the result with `geom_line()`.

Comment: `if ( !require(cobs) ){install.packages("cobs"); library(cobs) }; help(pac=cobs)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on IRTFM comment I was able to find the answer, here is the code:

```
library(cobs)
library(ggplot2)
df1<-data.frame(y=c(1,0.99,0.97,0.95,0.94,0.94,0.82,0.72,0.58,0.34,0.20,0.12,0.11,0), 
            time=c(3,4,7,8,10,11,13,14,15,17,20,22,23,24))

con2 <- rbind(c( 1,min(df1$time),1), 
          c(-1,max(df1$time),0)) 

Sb1 <- cobs(df1$time,df1$y, constraint="decrease", nknots=4,pointwise= con2,
        degree = 2)

summary(Sb1)
plot(Sb1, main='Survival Curve')
```

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add `ylim(0:1)` to your code:

```
ggplot(df1, aes(time,y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  ylim(0:1) +
  geom_smooth(method = "gam", formula = y ~ poly(x, 2),se=F)
```

[image]